# Pass by reference - object detection opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, pass-by-reference

Good Afternoon,
I need to proceed a piece of code two times at least and I was wondering if I can build a local function to be called outer the `main` environment. Of course it's possible, but I'm struggling with basic programming knowledge.

The code below is used to object recognition and I need to extract information about its center (at least two times) and radius (at least one time). The variables can be replaced without concern, that's the goal. The piece is written this way inside `main`:

```
//Detect edges using canny
int thresh = 100;
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
Canny(difframe, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );
        
//Find contours
findContours(canny_output, contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,Point(0,0));  
if (contours.size()==0)//check for recognition
{
    cout <<"Didn't find any contour"<< endl;
    return -1; 
}
vector<vector<Point>> contours_poly(contours.size());
vector<Point2f> centers (contours.size());
vector<float> radiuss(contours.size());
            
//Erase noise by choosing the greatest object and draw a circle to identify the moving body
int id = 0;
double area = 0.0, max_area = 0.0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
  approxPolyDP( contours[i], contours_poly[i], 3, true );
  minEnclosingCircle( contours_poly[i], centers[i], radiuss[i]);
  area = contourArea(contours[i], false);
  id = area > max_area ? i : id;
  max_area = max(max_area, area );
}
```

It could come before the `main` passing by value:

```
int object_recognition(Mat image){
     \\code here
     return id;
}
void main (){
    object_recognition(frame);
    Point center = center[id];
    float radius = radiuss[id];
 }
```

Or it could be passed by reference:

```
void object_recognition(Mat image, Point &center, float &radius){
       \\code here
}
void main (){
    Point center = (0,0); //declare variable
    float radius = 0.0;
    object_recognition(frame, center, radius);
}
```

What you adviced me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The second version seems slightly more flexible and slightly more natural but it doesn't seem like a big deal either way.

Comment: A `Mat const&` seems reasonable if you don't need to make changes to it. You could also return the center and radius as a `std::pair<Point, float>` instead of sending them in to the function. Then call with `auto&[center, radius] = object_recognition(image);` - It's a matter of opinion I guess and as such the question is not a good fit for SO.